# How does the async publish-subscribe of Spring Integration work?

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, asynchronous, spring-integration, publish-subscribe

I can implement asynchronous publish-subscribe in Spring Integration (SI) by using a task executor. It seems to work like a charm when deploying the SI war to Tomcat. However the real question is how the async part works in Tomcat (or in any other application server)?

I assume it uses threads but handling threads (without using thread pool defined in the app server) is quite dangerous in app server. As I didn't assign the task executor to the thread pool I assume SI will create threads on its own.

Could you please enlighten me?

Thanks, V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler

It's about the `taskScheduler` from the Java EE container, but the same rule is applied for the `taskExecutor`.

So, what you need just to get access to that `managed` `taskExecutor`, e.g. using JNDI and inject it to the `<publish-subscibe-channel>`.

Spring Integration is fully based on Spring Framework, so `<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5"/>` is just an instance of `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and it is responcible for the creation of threads.

Comment: It's not an issue in Tomcat but, yes other containers such as WebSphere require you to use managed threads. Artem's documentation link talks about the managed scheduler; Spring's bridge to the managed executor is `WorkManagerTaskExecutor`.

Comment: Hi Artem and Gary, thanks for the answer! So in app server I can't use the <task:executor id="async_executor" pool-size="50" />. Could you please send me an example how to get reference to the thread pool defined in app server and use it in <publish-subscribe-channel> ? Thanks, V.

Comment: It really depends on your EE server, e.g. WebSphere http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_config_managedexecutor.html. For Tomcat and JBOSS (which really is based on Tomcat for Web Profile) it doesn't matter. You can simply continue to use standard Spring's `<task:executor>`. However, you can install http://commonj.myfoo.de and try to managed executor from there. Anyway, any managed EE resource is available from JNDI.

Comment: Thanks again Artem! So I should define a bean like 
<bean id = "workManagerTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
  <property name="workManagerName" value="jndi/workManager" />
</bean> 
and use the workManagerTaskExecutor in the publish-subscribe?

Comment: Looks like. Sorry, haven't used `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` before